# I have an array of dictionaries with birthday in Python how do i sort it by ascending birthdays based on current day?

Tags: python

[{'birthday': '10/02/1987', 'id': '100003680523252', 'name': 'Station x Singapore'}, {'birthday': '05/21/1988', 'id': '100006891608724', 'name': 'Jessica x'}]

Comment: @SimonT It's not a duplicate of that as we're sorting a list here. The question should be closed anyway as there is no evidence of any working that has been done to solve this.

Comment: @Haidro ah my bad, I was lost in all the code.  Didn't notice the square brackets.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can do that as:

```
import datetime

a = [{'birthday': '10/02/1987', 'id': '100003680523252', 'name': 'Station x Singapore'}, {'birthday': '05/21/1988', 'id': '100006891608724', 'name': 'Jessica x'}]

a.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x['birthday'], '%m/%d/%Y'))

>>> print a
[{'birthday': '10/02/1987', 'id': '100003680523252', 'name': 'Station x Singapore'}, {'birthday': '05/21/1988', 'id': '100006891608724', 'name': 'Jessica x'}]
```

Here the `sort()` method sorts using lambda and the key as the birthday key of the list.

The `datetime` module is important since it helps to properly order the dates since python will not compare the date strings as dates but rather as strings where `11/11/2002` will be greater than `02/02/2056` (due to char-by-char comparison) which is clearly not what you want. Treating the dates as a `datetime` object will ensure that the `datetime` modules date comparison feature is used instead.

Hope that helps

Comment: OP would likely benefit from just a bit of explanation on how `list.sort` works with `key = lambda...` and the `datetime` module.  But good solution.

Comment: @SimonT, I have updated my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: It looks like you haven't been "more careful", as you said you would [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041710/counting-the-number-of-words-in-a-string-in-python/23041720?noredirect=1#comment35204042_23041720) (You prob need 10k+ rep to see this). Don't answer questions that don't deserve to be answered, please. You shouldn't encourage this.

Answer (score 0):

Define a comparison function that turns the birthday into [datetime objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html), something like:

```
def cmp(x, y):
    date_x = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y')
    date_y = datetime.datetime.strptime(y, '%d/%m/%Y')
    return date_x.cmp(date_y)
```